# sql join does not work when using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

**posts**

- id
- title
- content

**attachments**

- id
- post_id
- filename

**I would like to search for posts that have attachments whose filename contains ".txt".**

I've used all types of JOINs I know and still can't get it to work.

```
SELECT posts.*, filename FROM posts LEFT JOIN attachments ON posts.id = attachments.post_id WHERE filename LIKE '%.txt%'
```

SQL above does not return any rows. When I use RIGHT JOIN, it returns rows, but only the filename column has a value, the columns from the **`posts`** table all contains NULL.

Any help?

**UPDATE**

So sorry, it must have been a MySQL problem. I restarted the MySQL server and the query works now. Sorry, and thanks for the help.

Comment: On a sidenote here, I'd encourage you to use aliases when using joins as it is much easier to debug. Also if you're looking for txt files '%.txt' should do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
   posts.*, 
   filename 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN attachments 
  ON posts.id = attachments.post_id 
WHERE attachments.filename LIKE '%.txt%'
```

[DEMO:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e758/1)

Comment: both will show...seems like he missed `attachements` on `attachments.filename`

Comment: Does not need the 'attachments.', Pretty sure SQL will figure out filename belong to attachments table. I think there are something wrong with his data...